# CSS parsing libraries for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, css, parsing

I'm looking for some static library or open source project (in obj-c, released under some permissive license) to parse CSS in iPhone. Any recommendations?

Comment: can't you abuse `UIWebView` and javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found good library for parsing CSS - libCSS from the NetSurf web browser project. Released under MIT license, can be used without problems for commercial iPhone applications distributed via the AppStore.

It requires some code for the programmer to write (e.g. you need to provide your own DOM hierarchy handlers), and there are *no* examples available... but people from the NetSurf dev mailing lists are very helpful. In case of problems you can search the list for my questions.

[libCSS](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libcss/)

[NetSurf dev mailing list](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/lists/netsurf-dev)

Comment: How did you integrate this?

Comment: search for "starting with libcss" thread in that mailing list

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [htmlcxx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcxx/). It's pretty actively maintained, written in C++ and you can use it to parse HTML and CSS.

Of course, since it's written in C++, you can use it in your iPhone application with no problems at all.

Comment: Its not released under a permissive license though

Comment: indeed, it seems that LGPL is not appstore-friendly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459833/which-open-source-licenses-are-compatible-with-the-iphone-and-app-store

Comment: Actually, LGPL 2.1 is appstore friendly because it has the statically linking clause.  However htmlcxx contains code from tree.hh which is GPLed, but that's only used for the HTML part.  Perhaps you can ask the author nicely he would consider relicensing the CSS part under 2.1 which is independent of the GPLed code.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. You can use tree.hh as the author specifically provides a separate license when its used with htmlcxx. See http://tree.phi-sci.com/tree.hh.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken this project and made it easy to add to your iOS or OSX projects. Clone my [github project](https://github.com/dhoerl/htmlcxx) and add the html (and or css) folder to your project. There is an Xcode project too - so you can build and run the simple test provided by the original authors

Comment: This is released under LGPL which is not appstore-friendly