# IPad custom keypad styling?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

I am building a custom keypad for my application, i want to make the look and feel of button's like the default keypad of iPad.i have apply gradient on the button but its not give the same look and feel,

```
CAGradientLayer *layer1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    NSArray *colors1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9333f green:0.9333f blue:0.9411f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8235f green:0.8235f blue:0.8470f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,
                       nil];
    [layer1 setColors:colors1];
    [layer1 setFrame:self.sevenButton.bounds];
    self.sevenButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    self.sevenButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.sevenButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    self.sevenButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.sevenButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
    //self.sevenButton.layer.shadowRadius = 12;
    self.sevenButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f);
    [self.sevenButton.layer insertSublayer:layer1 atIndex:0];
    self.sevenButton.clipsToBounds = YES
```

it gives the look like this[image: the screen shot of output]

kindly suggest what could be the solution for that

thanks,

Comment: If you found my Answer helpful to you then Upvote and Accept.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Excellent Answer given for your Question at [How do I replicate the iOS keyboard appearance ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255000/how-do-i-replicate-the-ios-keyboard-appearance)

I don't need to give any Explanation as everything is given there. This is the Perfect Answer for your Question , I think so.