# How to create a QR Code reader for iOS

Tags: objective-c, camera, qr-code

I am developing an app for our local business. I already have the live camera in a `UIImageView`, now I need to know how to read QR codes from the `UIImageView` and display the content (0000-KKP0-2013) in a label.

So basically I need a QR code scanner which is reading a QR code and save the content in a String. I already used ZXing ("Zebra Crossing") but it is not compatible with iOS 6 and it won't work. Is there an easy code for getting the QR Code content in a String?

Thank you!

This is the code I am using in my .m file:

```
#import "ZBarSDK.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize vImagePreview;             

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    vImagePreview = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    //----- SHOW LIVE CAMERA PREVIEW -----
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;

    /*CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);*/

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
    [self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontCamera];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"QReader"
                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR: Versuch die Kamera zu öffnen ist fehlgeschlagen [%@]",error]
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        alert.tag = 1;

        [alert show];
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    [session startRunning];

    }

- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera {
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now I need to know how to read the QR code from the vImagePreview with the ZBarSDK. And I cant use a UIPickerView

Comment: This is quite different what You have already done. Yes - You have camera preview, but You still need necessary algorithm to decode any qr code visible in image. As there exists existing possibilities (Zbar, Libzbar, zXingObjc, etc) - then better use them.

Comment: zxing is compatible with iOS 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try ZBar: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html

We are using it successfully in our application which supports iOS 4 up to iOS 6.1

In my case I use `ZBarReaderView` - to see a camera preview, which automatically detects and returns scanned code.

You'll need:

```
#import "ZBarSDK.h"  


ZBarReaderView *readerView;
```

add this : `<ZBarReaderViewDelegate>`

and then:

```
[readerView.scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0]; 
readerView.readerDelegate = self;

[readerView start];

- (void)readerView:(ZBarReaderView *)view didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet *)syms fromImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) 
    {  
        NSLog(@"Did read symbols: %@", sym.data);

    }
}
```

Anyways, just follow these instructions:

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

and then try it out - see if it works for You.

**EDIT**

Here I uploaded example project I took from here: https://github.com/arciem/ZBarSDK

It has enabled front facing camera. Tested - successfully **reads qr code    using front facing camera**:

http://www.speedyshare.com/fkvqt/download/readertest.zip

or

Once application starts - front camera is shown - scanner is 200x200 large and as a subview.
http://www.speedyshare.com/QZZU5/download/ReaderSample-v3.zip

Comment: Thank you but I need the ZBarCaptureReader and there is no documentary about this in the documentation. I already have the live camera feed in a UIImageView but I don't know how to read the feed. And I don't have a  solid understanding of the AVCapture infrastructure. Can you please provide me some code? I'll update my question with my used code.

Comment: Thank you but how can I set the UIImageView that should be scanned? And should I set an Timer, so it scan In an Time interval or is this controlled by the SDK?

Comment: Is there a Way to use the front camera?

Comment: But I need the front cam, because the iPad is mounted in a Wall. Cant I just set a UIImageView to be Scanned by the ZBar SDK?

Comment: I dont get it how it work, can you please make it for me? Please iMessage me me if you like: david.goelzhaeuser@me.com

Comment: OK, your example will work but I cant use this Picker view thing, It must scan automatically, so without pushing a button. the Zbar code must scann a UIImageView for codes and display the string in a textview and must send the string to a database. I cant see how this will work with the SDK or with your example

Comment: Too bad for You, You cannot see :) This is just an example to start scanner on button touch and then remove scanner and show scanned image/code. This is easily tweak-able to show scanner all-time and update visible label with code that is scanned, without stopping scanner :) SDK is there for you to play with it!  :)

Comment: I am not a developer, I am just normal guy trying to make an app for his business, cant you provide me any code to solve this problem? Please!

Comment: Oh, I understand Your problem then. But I don't think I should do it all in Your place. Because - as far as I found out about this project - example I provided already is 90% done. It just needs different layout and a bit tweaked functionality.

Comment: It would be nice If you would only do the QR Code Scanning thing. I will do the Database thing and the rest. Could you do this for me?

Comment: Maybe. Explain more what changes You want to scanner?

Comment: Can you mail or iMessage me, so i can send you my existing project? david.goelzhaeuser@me.com

Comment: ZBar is the best! It took just a few hours to make the reading qrcodes feature work in my project!

Answer (score 2):

We looked into this not long ago. ZBar looks good, but it's LGPL-licensed, which is [not suitable for use on the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070734/15371).  In the end I went with [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC).

Comment: from: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/licensing.html 

"referring to the GPL, which is significantly different from the LGPL
referring to a different version of the LGPL; we intentionally use version 2.1, which has specific static linking exceptions.
not a lawyer either and too lazy to read the whole license
Basically, if you leverage the appropriate sections of the license, it should be fully compatible with the App Store restrictions and requirements."    -  so it would be ok to use it in appstore.

Comment: I wont use it in the AppStore, it is for private use only, so I can use it.

Comment: @Guntis: I'm aware of what ZBar say on the matter; I think they're wrong.  So do the FSF: http://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement

Answer (score 1):

if you want to test the qr codes here are some apps for iphone that might come in handy. [iphone qr scanner](http://www.iphonestop.net/best-5-iphone-qr-barcode-scanner-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

OP was looking for something that supported iOS6 two years ago, but for anyone else coming along, this one that I went with wraps the built-in iOS7 functionality:

https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking to implement this in Swift. Check this out:
https://github.com/aeieli/swiftQRCode

Need to change a few syntax errors, otherwise fully working on iOS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Check this out with apple natively implemented  [Qr code](https://github.com/JxbSir/JxbScanQR)