# How to play xiph.org audio codecs in iPhone/iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, vorbis, opus

I have music encoded in Vorbis format and also starded encoding some of my albums to the new Opus format. Is there a way I can copy and play them to my iPhone ? xiph.org wiki page states about vorbis support, that in the free software side, it's "work in progress", while it cites a radio stream and a video application that have Vorbis support, but what about audio support ?

To summarize the requirements:

- Vorbis support
- Opus support
- some way to copy or make the album available
- free software would be a plus, since proprietary software could be slow to adopt Opus and I could even add support for additional codecs myself by writing patches

[Edit: essential media player features required]

- Playlist support, etc.
- Flawless playback must be a strong guideline (for example, some players have audio decoding glitches every 5 minutes played)

http://wiki.xiph.org/Vorbis_Software_Players#iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capriccio music player for IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/capriccio-ultimate-music-player/id434828497?mt=8) supports FLAC, APE, WV, MPC, WAV, M4A, MP3, OGG, AIFF, CAF, MID, OPUS

I've used it on all my IOS devices (including iPad 2/3/Air and iPhone 4 & 6) with FLAC encoded music and never experienced audio glitches.

Comment: This one looks like a link only answer, can you provide more info please ?

Comment: Successfully using Capriccio for the last one to two years

Answer (score 1):

Open source licensing on iOS is [a difficult matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070734/3296598). [VLC for iOS](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) plays Opus and Vorbis. But as a music player it's quite useless.

Comment: Notice that the issues described in the reference are related to the more strict LGPL license. Current implementations of both libvorbis and libopus are BSD licensed and are in a similar class to Apache licenses. There's no problem using them and that can be seen in VLC usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 11 it supports native Opus streams, however you still need to encapsulate them in [CAF](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_intro/CAF_intro.html) format. For apps (and even in Safari) you might try to pass that CAF stuff with the audio/aac mimetype and should work.

Try with the `afconvert` available in macOS with something like this:

```
afconvert input.wav -f caff -d opus -b 32000 output.caf
```

There is a [test site](https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/) to try CAF in your Safari browser.

Source: https://hetzel.net/2017-06-12/ios-11-opus-support-in-podcast-feeds/