# Two versions of same static libraries conflict at run time

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, static-libraries, vlc

I am using ffmpeg 3.2 static libs (compiled for ios)
In the same project i have used mobilevlckit, which is using ffmpeg 2.0.2 static libs, compiled for ios but with different configuration. Both of them work well im separate projects. But putting them together causes crashes as name of the static libraries are same and they import each other and pickup the wrong versions. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot "fix" this, only 1 static symbol can be defined for an executable. This is a req of the linker. Also note that the LGPL has some murky legal issues when linked into an iOS app, you should have a lawyer review your use of LGPG or GPL source code in your iOS app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459833/which-open-source-licenses-are-compatible-with-the-apples-iphone-and-its-offici/1321681#1321681

Comment: Consider deploying either MobileVLCKit or the separate ffmpeg libraries dynamically to work-around the issue. However, it appears to be fishy in the first place that you need both MobileVLCKit and libavcodec in the same app. Are you use this is a good way to go?

Comment: Hi feepk,
Its not good way but vlc is using customised and very old(2.0.2) version of ffmpeg and i need to do some stuff using ffmpeg libraries which is not exposed by vlc framework. So i do not think i have another options.

Comment: Hi Shahid, I am facing the same issue. have you found any solution? thanks

Comment: Hi Harshal,
I was able to do it by changing a the Match-O type of my ffmpeg static lib to Relocatable object file but i had issues when uploading rtmp stream to remote server using that older version of ffmpeg which i compiled for iOS.
So i switched to ijkmediplayer for iOS. It is using another version (at least latest than the one used by VLC) of ffmpeg and ffplay and I compiled the same version of ffmpeg for ios using similar configuration as used by ijkmediaplyer and that did the trick for me.

Comment: @Jenis i have same issue as you, did you fixed it?